# How can I return multiple where clauses in different rows in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two queries that count the total of employees according to multiple conditions; the only thing that changes is the last two AND clauses; I don't know how I can return the results in the same query.
First Query

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM
(
SELECT
    E.NAME,
    E.LAST_NAME,
    E.BIRTH_DATE,
    E.ID
FROM
    EMPLOYEES E
WHERE E.BIRTH_DATE BETWEEN '2022-10-18 00:00:00' AND '2022-10-18 23:59:59'
AND E.NAME IS NOT NULL 
AND E.LAST_NAME IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY E.NAME, E.LAST_NAME, E.BIRTH_DATE,E.ID
) AUX;
```

Second Query

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM
(
SELECT
    E.NAME,
    E.LAST_NAME,
    E.BIRTH_DATE,
    E.ID
FROM
    EMPLOYEES E
WHERE E.BIRTH_DATE BETWEEN '2022-10-18 00:00:00' AND '2022-10-18 23:59:59'
AND E.NAME IS NULL 
AND E.LAST_NAME IS NULL
GROUP BY E.NAME, E.LAST_NAME, E.BIRTH_DATE,E.ID
) AUX;
```

Expected output:

| total |
| --- |
| 3 --first row |
| 5 --second row |

Comment: `and E.ID = 1 AND E.ID = 100`... assuming this is an employee id, how could a row have both an ID of 1 and 100? Does this query return anything? Should it be `and E.ID in (1, 100)`?

Comment: @Isolated sorry, I forgot to erase that part, the query is without that condition

Comment: You can refactor your query to use conditional aggregation or simply `union` the results.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest method (ie, least amount of re-writing) is simply `UNION` your queries together like this:

```
select 'null names' as col1, count(*)
from employees e
where e.name is null
  and e.last_name is null
union
select 'not null', count(*)
from employees e
where e.name is not null
  and e.last_name is not null;
```

| col1 | count(*) |
| --- | --- |
| null names | 1 |
| not null | 3 |

---

You could also use conditional aggregation, which uses less real estate and quite easy to read, and produce output in columns with this....

```
select 
  sum(case when e.name is null and e.last_name is null then 1 else 0 end) as null_names, 
  sum(case when e.name is not null and e.last_name is not null then 1 else 0 end) as not_null
from employees e;
```

| null_names | not_null |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |

---

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) filter (WHERE e.name IS NOT NULL AND e.last_name IS NOT NULL) as named
     , count(*) filter (WHERE e.name IS NULL AND e.last_name IS NULL) as unnamed
  FROM employees e
 WHERE e.birth_date BETWEEN '2022-10-18 00:00:00' AND '2022-10-18 23:59:59'
;
```

| named | unnamed |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 5 |

Unlike a union, this does not require two separate queries. Only a single pass
through the result set would be required.

But you asked for the results on separate rows, so...

```
SELECT unnest(ARRAY [
         count(*) filter (WHERE e.name IS NOT NULL AND e.last_name IS NOT NULL)
       , count(*) filter (WHERE e.name IS NULL AND e.last_name IS NULL)
       ])
  FROM employees e
 WHERE e.birth_date BETWEEN '2022-10-18 00:00:00' AND '2022-10-18 23:59:59'
;
```

| unnest |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 5 |

This makes the two results into an array and then unnests the result into
separate rows while still keeping the same query efficiency.